# React: Rendering second functional component when the first one is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to functional components, and struggle with figuring out how to render functional components that are not related to each other based on a parameter in `localStorage`. I have two components:

First component: gets a variable from the `localStorage`, and also has a button to update the same parameter.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { monthList } from "../common/lists";

const First = () => {
  const [focusDate, setFocusDate] = useState(
    Number(localStorage.getItem("focusDate"))
  );

  useEffect(() => {}, [focusDate]);

  const month = new Date(focusDate).getMonth();
  const year = new Date(focusDate).getFullYear();

  const onClick = () => {
    setFocusDate(focusDate - 504000000); //one week
    localStorage.setItem("focusDate", focusDate);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <i onClick={onClick} className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
      <div className="data">{`${monthList[month]} ${year}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default First;
```

The second component should also display the same data:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { monthList } from "../common/lists";

const Second = () => {
  const [focusDate, setFocusDate] = useState(
    Number(localStorage.getItem("focusDate"))
  );

  useEffect(() => {}, [focusDate]);

  const month = new Date(focusDate).getMonth();
  const year = new Date(focusDate).getFullYear();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="data">{`${monthList[month]} ${year}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Second;
```

Since I update the localStorage in the first component and I use useEffect hook in the second, my expectation is that whenever the data is re-rendered in the First component, it should also be re-rendered in the second. This doesn't happen, though. What am I missing here?

UPD:
Per suggestion below, created a parent component to pass the focusDate as props, however it returns undefined.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

//Components
import First from "../layout/First";

const DateHandler = () => {
  const [focusDate, setFocusDate] = useState(
    Number(localStorage.getItem("focusDate"))
  );

  useEffect(() => {}, [focusDate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <First focusDate={focusDate} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateHandler();
```

Comment: neither the props nor the local state change in `Second`, so there is no reason for it to rerender. `localStorage.getItem()` returns a static value, it doesn't listen to local storage updates.

Comment: You need to watch the value change of the first component in the second component, localstorage cannot be implemented

Comment: @hotpink how can I listen to those changes in the second component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use useEffect hook in the second, my expectation is that whenever
> the data is re-rendered in the First component, it should also be
> re-rendered in the second.

The dependency to the `useEffect` is the `state(focusDate)` of the `Second` component that isn't changed anywhere within the component. So, `Second` will not rerender.

**Solution:**

Move the `state` and the state updating code to a parent component and pass the `state` as props to `First` and `Second` components.

This is how the components should look like:

```
const DateHandler = () => {
  const [focusDate, setFocusDate] = useState(
    Number(localStorage.getItem('focusDate'))
  );

  const onClick = () => {
    setFocusDate((prevDate) => prevDate - 504000000); //one week
    localStorage.setItem('focusDate', focusDate);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <First focusDate={focusDate} onClickHandler={onClick} />
      <Second focusDate={focusDate} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateHandler();
```

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { monthList } from '../common/lists';

const First = ({ focusDate, onClickHandler }) => {
  const month = new Date(focusDate).getMonth();
  const year = new Date(focusDate).getFullYear();

  return (
    <div>
      <i onClick={onClickHandler} className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
      <div className="data">{`${monthList[month]} ${year}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

```
const Second = ({ focusDate }) => {
  const month = new Date(focusDate).getMonth();
  const year = new Date(focusDate).getFullYear();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="data">{`${monthList[month]} ${year}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Second;
```

Comment: These components don't have the same parent. I need some sort of a listening mechanism here that I can't figure out.

Comment: @Ruham Why not add a parent that doesn't have any JSX other than returning the child components?

Comment: I tried to create a parent DateHandler() that passes focusDate={focusDate} to the first component, however in the first component props.focusDate returns undefined. Could you please provide an example of your solution?

Comment: @Ruham make sure that the localStorage has `focusDate`. Add the parent's code to the question

Comment: Added, and the localstorage does have the value.

Comment: @Ruham You can remove the `useEffect`s. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! I implemented the changes, however I still get undefined NaN in the first component (for month and year).

Comment: log `focusDate` in the parent before returning the JSX and check if it has the value it should have.

Comment: Didn't include the parent in the App.js. Thanks!